# How to properly delete a map of pointers as key?

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary, delete-operator

I have a map of key/value pointers :

```
std::map<A*, B*> myMap;
```

What would be the proper way to liberate the memory of the key only?

I was thinking about doing this :

```
for (auto itr = _myMap.begin(); itr != _myMap.end(); itr++)
{
    if (certainCondition == true)
    {
        delete itr->first;
        itr->first = nullptr;
    }
}
```

Is it the correct way of doing it? Will my map keep `nullptr` as a key and future iteration will include `nullptr`?

Comment: What do you plan to do with the map after you free all the keys?

Comment: What is the use of the map if you delete all the keys?

Comment: You have to remove element from `map` before modifying the keys (else you have UB).

Comment: I don't know what you're *trying* to do, but the moment you starting trying to modify-in-place the keys to a standard map the car went over the cliff.

Comment: `std::map<std::unique_ptr<A>, B*>` seems more appropriate.

Comment: my example was bad. I would like to be able to remove one specific key and still keep the rest of my map

Comment: Copy the value to a new key value, then delete the original key and value.

Comment: @asdfasdf What would be the meaning of a value with a null key? And how would this be different from deleting the key/val pair from your map and making a new one with a null key?

Comment: @scohe001 sorry, I was not clear. I want to get rid of the values, but just without deleting the memory. I just want to delete the memory of the key. I'm just wondering if I just delete the key what will happen with the  values.

Comment: @asdfasdf If that is indeed true (you want to remove all keys from the map that fulfil a specific condition) then it almost seems you're having trouble grasping how to iterate a map with *erasure*. To do it properly you use the result of `erase`, which returns the "next" iteration point, so you don't need to increment the iterator. [Something like this](http://pastebin.com/YrfBCwJp). Is *that* what you're trying to do? (and keep in mind, I have no clue whether the mapped *value* should also be `delete`d; it's ownership isn't clear in your question).

Comment: @WhozCraig thank you, that was what I wanted. No I don't want to delete the mapped value

Comment: @asdfasdf at least one of the answers below now has that technique posted, though to be honest its a fairly common duplicate for the C++ tag here. Anyway, best of luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot modify the key of the container because it is used to define the ordering and changing it in place could invalidate the ordering. Furthermore, each key needs to be unique. Therefore, you need to remove the item from the map then clean up the memory.

If you already have the key:

```
myMap.erase(key);
delete key;
```

If you already have an iterator within the map:

```
A* keyCopy = itr->first;
myMap.erase(itr);
delete keyCopy;
```

#### Edit

Per your updated question:

```
auto itr = myMap.begin();
while (itr != myMap.end())
{
    if (certainCondition == true)
    {
        A* keyCopy = itr->first;
        itr = myMap.erase(itr);
        delete keyCopy;
    }
    else
    {
        ++itr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

erase() the element from the map, then delete the pointer that was acting as the key (if necessary, cached the pointer before the erase, if it does not exist anywhere else)

A map can only have one occurrence of each unique key. Even if it were possible - what would happen if you wanted to nullptr out more than one of the elements' keys? Nothing useful!

Answer (score 0):

The key is const. You should not be able to change it.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

Comment: so I should just do `delete itr->first`?

Comment: That will make the key useless. Copy or move the data to where you want it, then delete the whole entry.